# How to update Headers of CSV file in S3 file using JAVA

Tags: java, spring, csv, amazon-s3

I have a csv on S3 Location with below Headers:

Input S3 file: 
**number|dob|name|time|addr** 
1|aug 5|sam|5 pm|US

e.g output Expected:

**SrNumber|DOB|Name|Time|Address** 
1|aug 5|sam|5 pm|US

I need to rename/update the headers and drop the csv again to that location. 
Can you guide me achieve this using JAVA? 
Note: File can contain Millions of records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good place to start would be using the builtin `Scanner` class to ready the CSV input file in to your program. From there you could use the `FileWriter` class to write your updates back out to a file.
the imports are:

- `import java.util.Scanner;`
- `import java.io.FileWriter;`

Comment: Thanks, but if there are millions of records then it will cause memory issues and performance hit. I want to just update the Header of the csv file which is dropped by my unload command.